# how to run vba on protected sheets?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a dashboard on two sheets on excel and a third one with some formulas.
I put two buttons on the dashboard sheets to change the display. These buttons works on a macro that compile 6 more macros (to act differently according to the button's choice).
When I run it, I get an error saying the sheets I'm trying to work on are locked.
I'd like to locked all the sheets and still let the code runs. I don't need a password.
Here's the code for the macro of the buttons, which works without the sheets being protected.

```
Sub DropDown1_Change()
Sheets("Synthèse").Unprotect
Sheets("Prev").Unprotect
Sheets("graphs").Unprotect
If ActiveSheet.Name = "Prev" Then
Sheets("Synthèse").Activate
Select Case Sheets("Prev").Range("B380").Text
Case "1": S
Case "2": S
Case "3": S
Case "4": S
Case "5": S
Case "6": S
End Select
Sheets("Prev").Activate
Else
Select Case Sheets("Prev").Range("B380").Text
Case "1": S
Case "2": S
Case "3": S
Case "4": S
Case "5": S
Case "6": S
End Select
End If
Sheets("Synthèse").Protect
Sheets("Prev").Protect
Sheets("graphs").Protect
End Sub
```

Comment: "I get an error saying the sheets..." does not say (almost) anything... What error, on which line?

Comment: See the use of `UserInterfaceOnly` in the linked duplicate.